# How to do this Linq-to-Sql join?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

Please do not give me help in lamba

```
I have two tables. 
Employees:   
pk           
name        

ExpenseTeamMembers: 
pk                        
expMgrPk
empPk

Example: pk      expMgrPk     empPk     
     1         7          81
     2         7          101
     3         13         99
     4         13         22
     5         13         56
```

Basically the first table is a list of employees and the second is a table for keeping track of which employees belong to which manager.

The first sql lookup works and mgr is getting me the pk of the selected name in the combo box.

What I am trying to do in the join is lookup the expMgrPk and see which employees belong to it and return their names instead of their pk. I am pretty off and need a little help. Again please do not give me help in lamba!!  Thanks

```
    private void cboManagers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cboManagers != null)
        {
            string selectedMgr = (string)cboManagers.SelectedValue;

            using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                int mgr = (from f in db.employees
                          where f.name == selectedMgr
                          select f.pk).FirstOrDefault();

                var emps = (from m in db.employees
                            join t in db.expenseTeamMembers on m.pk equals t.pK
                            where t.expMgrPk == mgr
                            select m.name).ToList();
                lstSelected.DataSource = emps;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you have your relationships set up correctly you shouldn't have to deal with the PKs directly, ever.

Comment: Your join should be `on m.pk equals t.empPk`. Also, I haven't worked in winforms, but can you not store a value and text in the listbox? This way you could avoid the `mgr` query and simply pass the listbox selected value to the `emps` query.

Comment: The selected manager is a combobox not a listbox. I fixed my equals and it is still not working. I think i am missing a line yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linq-to-sql, you can write joins more easily by writing two `from` statements combined with a `where` statement. Something like this:

```
var emps = (from f in db.employees
            from m in db.expenseTeamMembers
            where m.pk == mgr && f.pk == m.empPk
            select f.name).ToList();
```

I've found this syntax to be easier and when your code is compiled, the query is converted to a traditional T-SQL join.

Comment: tried that and this... no go... var emps = (from m in db.employees
                                from t in db.expenseTeamMembers
                                where t.pK == mgr && m.pk == t.empPk
                                select m.name).ToList();

Comment: I'd debug your query by temporarily replacing the variable mgr with a known pk of a manager and see what happens. The syntax of the code is correct so the problem is elsewhere. Do you get an error or does the query not return anything?

Comment: Just realized something: in the first query, it seems you're querying for the name of the manager in the employee table so the result is null!!! Shouldn't it be from f in db.expenseTeamMembers where f.name == selectedMgr ??

Comment: mgr is a valid manager. in the first query all i am doing is taking the selected text value of the combobox and getting its pk

Comment: What happens when you do (from m in db.expenseTeamMembers where m.pk == 1 select m.empPk).ToList(); Note that I put 1 but replace it with a know ID to test.

Comment: I want to query the employee table because all i am trying to do is take the text value (name) and get its pk from the emps table so i can use it to lookup in the manager table

Comment: Put it this way when I do this it will correctly return all the emp pks for the selected manager. I need to do the join because i need to see the name instead of the pk.                                   var emps = (from u in db.expenseTeamMembers
                    where u.expMgrPk == mgr
                    select u.empPk).ToList();

Comment: It's not clear then: I wrote where m.pk == mgr && f.pk == m.empPk so that 1) the pk of the manager is equal to the mgr parameter and then 2) I'm matching from the same table the empPk to the pk of the employee table so that I can get the employee's name with f.name.

Comment: Yeah i get that. Not sure why its giving me a list with 0

Comment: Iv confirmed the first query
the expMgrPk is 101 in the mgr table and the first query returns 101

Comment: I don't what to say; the where clause should work. Very weird.

Comment: It was an issue with invalid records in my table... I apologize. Your codes now works! Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: Also I believe I didnt need the   && m.pk == t.empPk

Comment: You DO need it because that's what's creating the join with the employee table: we want the employeeIDs of the manager and employee tables to be the same!!! No problem for the help, I've been helped plenty so I know the feeling. Happy coding!